# Typing in 2 different applications at the same time

Tags: applications

I am typing code on Google Docs through Chrome. What I want is for an app to enter whatever I type in the Google Docs into an open XCode editor. This way while I am done typing code I can check for errors. The hard way is to finish coding and select everything and then copy and paste.
In short: I am looking for an app that helps you type in 2 different applications at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know no, mostly due to the way the OS X window manager is setup you need to have the text area to have focus to receive key input (but not all key events).

However, this is not to say it's *not* possible, but I can't think of a way to do it 'live', as in sending the text char by char. If I was looking at doing it basically what I'd be trying to to basically keylog myself ([list of keyloggers](http://foliovision.com/2010/01/17/keyloggers-mac-os-x)), and hack a script to switch to Chrome, dump the text and switch back to Xcode, but that's about as gracefully as I can think of and even that's a pretty ugly way to do it.

There's probably a nicer way to do it, but I'd start with the keylogger and build from there.